# Is it allowed to use VMware integrated containers without enterprise plus?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, licensing

We use a VMware VCenter installation with a Essentials Plus license.

The official [VIC Documentation](https://vmware.github.io/vic-product/) says the following

> **Get vSphere Integrated Containers**
>   To obtain the latest official release of vSphere Integrated Containers, go to the vSphere Integrated Containers download page on vmware.com. This page includes the downloads for both vSphere Integrated Containers Engine and vSphere Integrated Containers Registry. You need a **vSphere Enterprise Plus License** to download an official, supported release of vSphere Integrated Containers.
>
> *You can also **obtain open-source releases** of vSphere Integrated Containers that are more recent than the latest official release:*

How to understand that?

a) If you **do** have a vSphere Enterprise Plus License you may download open-sources releases, **too**
b) If you **don't** have a vSphere Enterprise Plus License you can download open-source releases **instead**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need distributed switches to run VIC so hence you need a licence that supports that feature.